# Is it haram to pray Fajr befor duhr?

Tags: salat, salat-qada

If i don`t manage to wake up for Fajr, can i pray once i wake up after sunrise or would it be Haram as the sun rises between the horns of the devil according to the following hadeeth:

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The time for Subh (Fajr) prayer lasts from the beginning of the pre-dawn so long as the sun has not yet started to rise. When the sun starts to rise then stop praying, for it rises between the two horns of the Shaytaan.”

Jazakum allah kher brothers and sisters

Comment: There is another Hadith which is **Al-Bukhaari (548)**. Our Prophet (SAW) says, delay your prayer if the top edge of sun raise.

Comment: Al-Bukhaari (548) and Muslim (1371) narrated that Ibn ‘Umar said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “When the top edge of the sun has risen, then delay praying until it has risen above the horizon, and when the lower part of the sun has set, delay praying until it is fully set.”

Comment: Yes this is the hadith

Answer (score 3):

For any obligatory prayer that you missed due to sleeping, or forgetting you have to perform it once you realize you missed it regardless of the time.

Anas ibn Maalik said: “The Messenger of Allah(saw) said: ‘If one of you sleeps and misses a prayer, or forgets it, then let him pray it as soon as he remembers, because Allah(swt) says (interpretation of the meaning): ‘… and perform al-salaah for My remembrance.’ [Ta-Ha 20:14]” (Reported by Muslim).

Abu Hurayrah reported that the Messenger of Allah(saw) said: “Whoever forgets the prayer, let him pray as soon as he remembers, because Allah(swt) says (interpretation of the meaning): ‘… and perform al-salaah for My remembrance.’ [Ta-Ha 20:14]” (Reported by Muslim).

Anas ibn Maalik reported that the Messenger of Allah(saw) said: “Whoever forgets a prayer, let him pray it as soon as he remembers, for there is no expiation for it except this.” (Reported by Muslim, 1102).

Answer (score 0):

> Ibn 'Umar said, "Allah's Apostle said, 'Do not pray at the time of sunrise and at the time of sunset.' " Ibn 'Umar said, "Allah's Apostle said, 'If the edge of the sun appears (above the horizon) delay the prayer till it becomes high, and if the edge of the sun disappears, delay the prayer till it sets (disappears completely).' " (Bukhari Volume 1, Book 10, Number 557)
>
> Narrated Ibn 'Umar: I pray as I saw my companions praying. I do not forbid praying at any time during the day or night except at sunset and sunrise. (Bukhari Volume 1, Book 10, Number 563)
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Apostle forbade the offering of two prayers:
>   1. after the morning prayer till the sunrises.
>   2. after the 'Asr prayer till the sun sets. (Bukhari Volume 1, Book 10, Number 562)

The hadiths specifically mention not praying at the moment *between Fajr prayer and sunrise*. As you woke up *after sunrise*, the prayer is thus **permissible**. And it's perhaps obligatory.

Comment: These timings apply to optional prayers only. Missed obligatroy prayers can be performed at any time.