# How long to wait after sunrise before offering fajr prayer?

Tags: salat, time, fajr

Assalamu'Alaikum Fellow Community members,

This is my very first question to the community and it's a simple one.

Is there a hadith or quranic verse which tells how long one has to wait after sunrise before offering the Fajr prayer? Obviously this is when one has missed the fajr time and woken up right after sunrise time has past.

Answers with authentic references will be much appreciated.

Comment: Take look on [this](http://islamqa.info/en/49019) and [this](http://islamqa.info/en/111783)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it haram to pray Fajr befor duhr?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16975/is-it-haram-to-pray-fajr-befor-duhr)

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean performing the missed fajr prayer? If yes, then you can perform it anytime after sunrise or during the day, no need to wait. Except that if you want to perform it along with your zohr/asr/maghrib prayer then make sure u first perform zohr/asr/maghrib and then fajr salah because the time of zohr has entered.

Answer (score 2):

Alsalam You have to wait for 20 minutes after sunrise. You can easily find the sunrise time each day on any website.

The reason why prayer at these times is not allowed is so as to avoid any resemblance to the kuffaar who prostrate to the sun when it rises as a greeting to it and to express their joy.
 The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) was keen to put a stop to all things that may lead to shirk, or that might involve any resemblance to the mushrikeen.(non Muslims but specifically those who don't belive in god)

The Hadith I found about this is:

“There is no prayer after the Fajr until the sun (sufficiently) rises; and there is no prayer after the ‘Asr until the sun completely sets.” [M-1041, agreed upon]

The other time mentioned here is after Asr prayer till Maghreb prayer. (Again for the same reason as before.)

Hope I helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

A missed fard prayer can be performed immediately at any time once one recall it.

There's no difference of opinion that I know of that would hinder you from offering an obligatory prayer you've missed at any moment you've recalled it:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "If anyone forgets a prayer he should pray that prayer when he remembers it. There is no expiation except to pray the same." Then he recited: "Establish prayer for My (i.e. Allah's) remembrance." (20.14). ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:597))

And you should do so without waiting or delay. Especially if this is not a huge among of prayers: for example if you were ill and couldn't pray for a week or in worst case because of laziness. However the matter of qada' is disputed among scholars, but the majority view is rather that one should perform missed prayers as qada' or at least replace them by nafl (a second view) and the few totally disagreeing positions could be refuted eve based on the above hadith.

Finally be aware that in many schools of fiqh a qada' of nafl or sunnah or more general optional prayers s also allowed, but you must be aware that for optional prayers you should avoid times where praying is makruh or haraam according the view of some madhhabs. This qualification of makruh or even haraam only applies to prayers that are not ordered therefore the hadith says once you remember a prayer you "*should pray*" not one you "could pray" so prayer one is obliged to pray should be performed anytime as
mentioned in the rhym from [Matn ibn 'Achir](http://www.ma7dhara.com/2014/07/26/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%B4%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%86/)  ابن عاشر (al-maliki):

> فَجْـرٌ رَغِيبَـةٌ وَتُقْـضَـى لِلـزَّوَالْ * * * وَالْفَرْضُ يُقْـضَـى أَبَـداً وَبِالتَّـوَالْ
> Fajr is a Raghībah and it is made up until high noon. | Fard prayers are made up without any end time limit and in
> succession (in the proper order).

Which makes clear that a missed obligatory prayer must be prayed as soon as possible without any delay or respect for prayer time preferences.

**Summary**
If you mean the fard (obligatory) prayer you can/should pray it once you have performed wudu' regardless of the time.
The only case were you may have to wait is if you have a bunch of fard prayers to offer in that case respecting the order and adding the missed prayer to its "timing" is regarded as the better choice.
For missed optional prayers one must avoid time periods were praying them is regarded as frowned upon or even haram.

See also [What do I do if I missed joined prayers?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/what-do-i-do-if-i-missed-joined-prayers)