# Is it recommended to perform Qada' of nafl/sunna prayers?

Tags: practical-islam, fiqh, salat-qada, nafl

In this [post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/what-do-i-do-if-i-missed-joined-prayers) there's a quote of a maliki point of view regarding how to make up at least fajr prayer (malikis distinct between the sunna and fard of fajr by calling the fard sobh). I also know that some schools a allow making up witr, but don't exactly know the limitations.

My Question is:

What are/is the view(s) of scholars on performing qada' for nafl/sunna prayers, is it recommended, if yes how and are there any limitation (for example can I do qada' when ever I recall it as the case for fard according the sahih hadith:

> "He who forgets the prayer, or he slept (and it was omitted), its expiation is (only) that he should observe it when he remembers it."

. or can I only make up the prayers I missed actually).

Comment: I think "allowed" is not the correct word to use in this context. Nafl/sunnah prayers are voluntary actions. So whether you make a niyyah for a make up or another (new) nafl/sunnah prayer does not change it's degree - either way that's going to be a voluntary prayer at most. That's "allowed" is not the correct word here.

Comment: Maybe "recommended" would fit?

Answer (score 0):

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

### Is it recommended to perform Qada' of nafl/sunna prayers?

Yes. It is strongly recommended to perform Qada' of nafl/sunna prayers. Following Hadith narrations are proof for it

> ‘I went over to Abu Ja’far (asws) and I was a youth, so **he (asws)
> described the voluntary (Salāt)** for me, and the Fasts. So he (asws)
> saw the heaviness of that in my face, and he (asws) said to me:
> ‘**This is not like the Obligatory (Salāt) which if one were to
> neglect it, would be destroyed. But rather, it is the voluntary. If
> you were too busy from it or neglect it, MAKE UP FOR IT**. They (the
> people) would be disliking if their deeds were to be Raised as
> complete one day, and one day - deficient. Allah (azwj) Mighty and
> Majestic is Saying (in Quran)
>
> > [70:23] Those who are constant at their Prayer,
>
> and they were disliking if they were to pray Salāt until the day
> declines, and that the gates of the sky are open when the day (starts
> to) decline’.
>
> [Al Kafi V 3 – The Book Of Salāt CH 84 H 1 (page 18)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol3/AlKafiV3-TheBookOfSalat(6).pdf)

The following hadith narrations specify the total number of rak'ahs, both obligatory and optional, that must be prayed a day.

> (It has been narrated) from Abu Abdullah (asws) having said: ‘**The
> Obligatory and the optional (Salāts) are fifty one (51) Rak’at** –
> from it are two Rak’at after the night (to be prayed) seated, counted
> as one Rak’at prayed while he is standing. The Obligatory from these
> are seventeen Rak’at, and the optional are thirty four Rak’at’.
>
> [Al Kafi V 3 – The Book Of Salāt CH 84 H 2 (page 18)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol3/AlKafiV3-TheBookOfSalat(6).pdf)

> ‘I asked Abu Abdullah (asws) about **the most superior of what the
> Sunnah has flowed with, from the Salāt**. So he (asws) said: ‘**The
> complete fifty** (Rak’at and one while sittingso 51 in total)’.
>
> And it is reported by Al-Husayn Bin Saeed, from Muhammad Bin Sinan –
> similar to it.
>
> [Al Kafi V 3 – The Book Of Salāt CH 84 H 4 (page 19)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol3/AlKafiV3-TheBookOfSalat(6).pdf)

In following narrations Imams of Ahlul-Bayt are strongly recommending to fulfill missed optional prayers

> ‘Abu Abdullah (asws) said: ‘**Fulfil whatever is lost by you from the
> Salāts** of the daytime, at daytime, and whatever is lost by you from
> the Salāts of the night, at night-time’. I said, ‘Can I fulfil two
> Al-Witr (Salāt) during a night?’ So he (asws) said: ‘Yes, **fulfil
> Witr (Salāt)**, always’.
>
> [Al Kafi V 3 – The Book Of Salāt CH 85 H 3 (page 30)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol3/AlKafiV3-TheBookOfSalat(6).pdf)

> ‘Ismail Bin Jabir asked Abu Abdullah (asws), so he said, ‘May Allah
> (azwj) Keep you (asws) well! **Upon me are a lot of (outstanding)
> optional (Salāts)**. So how should I deal with these?’ **So he (asws)
> said: ‘Fulfil them’**. So he said to him (asws), ‘They are more
> numerous than that’. He (asws) said: ‘Fulfil these’. I said, ‘I cannot
> (even) count them’. He (asws) said: ‘Be at it’.
>
> Al Kafi V 3 – The Book Of Salāt CH 85 H 4 (page 30)

**Conclusion**

Total number of daily rak'ahs is 50 (51 or 52). This includes obligatory and optional (nafl/sunna) rak'ahs. And performing Qada' of Optional (nafl/sunna) rak'ahs is strongly recommended (Mustahab).

Answer (score -2):

Only obligatory prayers (Fard) have Qada, for Nafl/Sunnah prayer you don't need Qada.

Comment: That's simply wrong

Comment: For whoever is reading this comment, just to clarify:
In Sunnah, that's the right thing. "Only obligatory prayers (Fard) have Qada".
In Shia, according to previous answer, Nafl/Sunnah prayer need Qada too.