# Tahajjud prayer

Tags: salat-qada, tahajjud

I had promised my self that i would offer tahajjud prayer every night. I was continuing this for 6 days but today when alarm rang i thought to take a nap for just 5 minutes. Normally i pray tahajjud before 1and half hour of athan of fajr. When i woke up it was the time of fajr just before 2 mins of athan. Now i feel very sad for it as my witr prayer also got qadha. I was unable to maintain my intention.

**Can i pray the qadha namaz of today's tahajjud ?**

I guess it would not be tahajjud then.

Is there a way to fulfill ?

At last i think shaitan made me do that so tell me someways to ensure completion what i have intended without any risk of getting slept again sowewhat like dua.

Comment: Related post [Qada' of nafl/sunna prayers](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33450/qada-of-nafl-sunna-prayers)