# Can we offer Qadha of a prayer after Fard of Fajr and Asr?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings, salat-qada

Voluntary prayers are forbidden after the Fard of Fajr and Asr till the time for the respective prayers are over. But can we offer qadha of a prayer at that time?

Comment: This is covered in my answer on [What do I do if I missed joined prayers](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/what-do-i-do-if-i-missed-joined-prayers) therefore it is a duplicate.